# XML Deserialize duplicate nodes to an object

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I have a following xml with duplicate nodes named("address") and I need to deserialize these "address" nodes to one object:

```
<dealer id="8569" ed="0">
  <name hide="0">some name</name>
  <url>http://www.some.com</url>
  <address hide="0" />
  <address>
    <line1>text1</line1>
    <line2>text2</line2>
    <line3>text3</line3>
    <town>Town</town>
    <postcode>Postcode</postcode>
  </address>
</dealer>
```

I need to deserialize it to the following class:

```
public class Dealer
{
    public Dealer()
    {
        _address = new Address();
    }

    [XmlAttribute("id")]
    public long Id { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("name")]
    public string Name{ get; set; }

    [XmlElement("url")]
    public string Url{ get; set; }

    [XmlElement("address")]
    public Address Address{ get; set; }

}    
public class Address
{
    [XmlElement("line1")]
    public string Line1{ get; set; }

    [XmlElement("line2")]
    public string Line2 { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("line3")]
    public string Line3 { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("county")]
    public string County{ get; set; }

    [XmlElement("town")]
    public string Town{ get; set; }

    [XmlElement("postcode")]
    public string Postcode{ get; set; }
}
```

When this xml is deserialized to above class, it always gets the first "address" node, however, I need the second node to be picked up. How can I do this?

Comment: On second read, did you need to _combine_ the address data? That is, Line1, Line2, Line3, County, Town, Postcode _AND_ the "hide=0" value? Or you can just ignore the first address element node altogether?

Comment: Why you don't use the list of Address, just curious?

Comment: @ChrisSinclair yes,i want combine the address data?

Comment: you just need one address for what? show on UI?

Comment: @Miro, then you intend to add a `Hide` property on `Address` and use it in your program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short of changing your XML schema, all I can think of is having your `Dealer` class implement `IXmlSerializable` and implement the associated `ReadXml` method to use the desired xml node. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.ixmlserializable.readxml.aspx

Other than that, you could alter your `Dealer.Address` to be a collection/array of `Address` objects which are compatible to *both* representations then after deserialization ignore/remove the empty address from the collection.